# Как подключить slick slider если блок с img я вставляю в html через js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slick.js

Всем привет,
не могу подключить slick slider к блоку который выводится в html через jquery.
есть некий файлик JSON с которого я вытаскиваю изображение в html

```
var out = '';
for (var key in data) {
       out += '<div class="single-goods">';
       out += `<img class="single_goods_img" src="${data[key].image}">`;
       out += `<img class="single_goods_img" src="${data[key].image2}">`;
       out += `<img class="single_goods_img" src="${data[key].image3}">`;
       out += '</div>';
```

и все выводится и отображается.

```
<div class="single-goods">
 <img class="single_goods_img" src="images/jewelry/1.jpg">
 <img class="single_goods_img" src="images/jewelry/2.jpg">
 <img class="single_goods_img" src="images/jewelry/3.jpg">
</div>
```

slick slider подключаю корректно, но если подключить к классу single-goods, то ничего не происходит, и консоль тоже пустая.
    $('.single-goods').slick();

если создать этот же блок .single-goods с img в HTML то все работает как часы.!!!

подскажите, кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и как быть в таком случае??

Comment: $(document).find('.single-goods').slick();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И так работает.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
 $("body").append('<div class="single-item">\
  <div><img src="https://static.fotopoisk.com.ua/media/uploads/bengalskij-kot-30-2.jpg"></div>\
  <div><img src="https://from-ua.com/upload/articles/2016/08/08/images/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%823.jpg"></div>\
  <div><img src="http://murkote.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/15-siberian-cat.jpg.pagespeed.ce.pYzQdgZqrR.jpg"></div>\
  <div><img src="http://mykoshka.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Mein-kyn.jpg"></div></div>');

 $('.single-item').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
 });
});
```

```css
img{
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css"/>

<button>Добавить HTML</button>
```